# Proof Estimator is Locally Regular

Tags: estimation, convolution

In order to rely on Hajek-Le Cam Convolution Theorem, I tried to show that a given root-n consistent estimator was locally regular.

In particular, suppose $\{T_n\}$ is a $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimator for $\theta$ at $\theta=\theta_0$ and take $\{\theta_n\}\subset \Theta$, s.t. $\sqrt{n}\left(\theta_n- \theta\right) \to t \in \mathbb{R}^k$.

$\{T_n\}$ is a locally regular estimator for $\theta$ at $\theta=\theta_0$ if for any such sequence, under $P_{\theta_n}$, $\sqrt{n}\left(T_n - \theta_n\right)\to_d Z$ as $n\to \infty$, where $Z$ depends on $\theta_0$ but not on $t$.

**My question**:

**How to show a particular estimator, say OLS, NLS or some other, is indeed (or not) locally regular?**

If $\sqrt{n}(\theta_n-\theta_0) \to t$, how *not to* get $\sqrt{n}(T_n - \theta_0) \to_d N(t,V)$ (for some $V$)?

PS: I'm at a semi-low level in statistics (no/basic knowledge of measure theory).